# C4D mograph like behaviour in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

i'm trying to replicate the mograph like behaviour in Animation Nodes. I'm trying to grasp the concepts here and new to this so bit more explanation would be great. I searched but could not find the info i was looking for so if you can help I would really appreciate it.

So i have a plates that are on certain locations. I was trying to randomly scale them from 0 to 1 and I think I got it. Heres the screenshot:

[image: screenshot 1]
Screenshot 01

By adjusting the Effect Strength from -1 to 1 I'm able to get what I want - randomly scale images from 0 to 1. I hope this is a correct/elegant solution, so I'm open to better ones if they exists.

After that I wanted to add location/translation - like let the plates start from off screen and then fly to their original locations. I added following nodes:

[image: screenshot 2]
Screenshot 02

Unfortunately in this case the change in Math node iterates and continues to grow without stopping and I was not able to find a way to break the loop.

Could you please let me know how this is done? Is this approach an optimal one? I suppose rotation will be dome as translation too right?

Well thank you in advance for your support. I also attached the blend file so feel free to look. Thanks.

[ANIMATION_NODES_BLEND_FILE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15427656/Blender/animation_nodes_test.blend)

Comment: As the screenshots were included into your question from your dropbox now they aren't visible (likely they don't exist on dropbox anymore) and your question is less clear for anyone reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ID Key node. It basically allows you to recover positions from objects previously stored. Use it instead of the object transform input.

Positions are stored on the viewport.

See this documentation.

http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/object/object_id_key.html